# How to define stopping points along a horizontal slider unity widget in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a horizontal slider widget for a mod for a popular video game and I've almost got everything I need but I don't know how to set stopping points along the slider. I need at least 3 stopping points that I can then reference as SliderValueAtZero,SliderValueAtTen, and SliderValueAtTwenty. The slider itself works fine I just need it to not be a continuous line with infinite decimals. Any help is appreciated.

```
public override string SettingsCategory() => "Pawn Wealth";

        public override void DoSettingsWindowContents(Rect inRect)
          {
            this.settings.PawnSkillValue1 = Widgets.HorizontalSlider(inRect.TopHalf().TopHalf(), this.settings.PawnSkillValue, 0f, 20f, true, "Pawn Skill Value: " + this.settings.PawnSkillValue + "\nDetermines the value of a pawns skills", "0", "20");
          }
```

Comment: so you want to round it up/down to meet that??  just round the number on change

Comment: As the slider functions now it smoothly moves from 0-20 hitting all points in between like 9.19748. I'd like it to stop at 10 but I don't know how to tell it to do that.

Comment: So set it to whole numbers, and divide the values so its 1,2,3 etc.... or round the number on change

Comment: That sounds great. How do I do that? Sorry, I'm still learning.

Comment: look at the slider properties.. and then when you come to use the value *10 it.

Comment: I think I titled my post incorrectly, my apologies. I've corrected it. I cannot look at any properties. I'm coding in c#.

Comment: then you obviously arent using unity - as the slider is in unity....... you are just putting code behind it  (and yes even in c'# you can look at properties)

Comment: Is this an editor script or are you displaying the slider in the App?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing in the wild here that what you are using is a [`GUI.HorizontalSlider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.HorizontalSlider.html).

**Is this an editor script?**

Because if not you shouldn't use the stuff from `GUI` at all but rather use the [UI System -> `Slider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider.html) component.

This said you could simply round the value to the according multiple you need. Unity handles User input first so you can drag the slider around "invisibly" but you will see the effect after rounding:

```
var temp = Widgets.HorizontalSlider(inRect.TopHalf().TopHalf(), this.settings.PawnSkillValue, 0f, 20f, true, "Pawn Skill Value: " + this.settings.PawnSkillValue + "\nDetermines the value of a pawns skills", "0", "20");
this.settings.PawnSkillValue1 = Mathf.Round(temp / 10f) * 10f;
```

This will allow values of `0`, `10` and `20`.

[image]

---

But as said you should rather use a [UI System -> `Slider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider.html) component. Maybe your custom widget thingy does even do exactly that .. we don't know since we don't see the code.

Here you could attach a listener to the [`onValueChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-onValueChanged.html) event and have a method like e.g.

```
public Slider slider;
public Text text;
public float roundToMultipleOf = 0.5f;

public void HandleChange(float value)
{
    slider.value = Mathf.Round(value / roundToMultipleOf) * roundToMultipleOf;
    text.text = slider.value.ToString("#0");
}
```

[image]

[image]